# Magento 2 Travis Unit tests errors

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit, travis

I've set up Travis with Magento 2 unit tests to test our code. My PHPunit config is like this:

File `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.custom.xml.dis`:

```
 <testsuite name="Magento Unit Tests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../dev/tools/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../dev/tools/*/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../lib/internal/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../lib/internal/*/*/*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <!-- <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../setup/src/*/*/Test/Unit</directory> -->
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../vendor/*/module-*/Test/Unit</directory>
        <!-- <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../vendor/*/framework/Test/Unit</directory> -->
        <!-- <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../vendor/*/framework/*/Test/Unit</directory> -->
    </testsuite>
```

I've commented out some rules, because they contain known Magento 2 bugs. If I run the tests via the command line everything is fine:

```
........................................................... 11269 / 12140 ( 92%)
........................................................... 11328 / 12140 ( 93%)
........................................................... 11387 / 12140 ( 93%)
........................................................... 11446 / 12140 ( 94%)
........................................................... 11505 / 12140 ( 94%)
........................................................... 11564 / 12140 ( 95%)
........................................................... 11623 / 12140 ( 95%)
........................................................... 11682 / 12140 ( 96%)
........................................................... 11741 / 12140 ( 96%)
........................................................... 11800 / 12140 ( 97%)
........................................................... 11859 / 12140 ( 97%)
........................................................... 11918 / 12140 ( 98%)
........................................................... 11977 / 12140 ( 98%)
........................................................... 12036 / 12140 ( 99%)
........................................................... 12095 / 12140 ( 99%)
............................................

Time: 51.83 seconds, Memory: 572.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 12137, Assertions: 36333, Incomplete: 41, Skipped: 150.
```

When I run the same test in Travis, i'm getting another result:

```
...........................................................  7375 / 12140 ( 60%)
...........................................................  7434 / 12140 ( 61%)
...........................................................  7493 / 12140 ( 61%)
....................................IIIIIIIIIIIII..........  7552 / 12140 ( 62%)
...........................................................  7611 / 12140 ( 62%)
...........................................................  7670 / 12140 ( 63%)
...........................................................  7729 / 12140 ( 63%)
...........................................................  7788 / 12140 ( 64%)
.......................................................PHP Fatal error:  Class Mock_OrderPaymentExtensionInterface_4f2544b4 contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtensionInterface::getVaultPaymentToken) in /home/travis/build/xxx/xxx.nl/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(290) : eval()'d code on line 1
Fatal error: Class Mock_OrderPaymentExtensionInterface_4f2544b4 contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtensionInterface::getVaultPaymentToken) in /home/travis/build/xxx/xxx.nl/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(290) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

My script line in `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
   - $COMPOSER_BIN_DIR/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.custom.xml.dist
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Why are the unit tests in failing only in Travis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` before the unit tests, instead of after the unit tests. Switching  both commands solved the problem.